# How to identify ip address for instance in Prometheus result?

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, docker-swarm, prometheus-node-exporter

I've a docker swarm configured with nodeA as manager and nodeB as worker and have Promethues installed as docker container on nodeA with `prometheus.yml` file as -

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 'localhost:9090'

  - job_name: 'node resources'
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['tasks.node']
        type: 'A'
        port: 9100
    params:
      collect[]:
        - cpu
        - meminfo
        - diskstats
        - netdev
        - netstat

  - job_name: 'node storage'
    scrape_interval: 1m
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['tasks.node']
        type: 'A'
        port: 9100
    params:
      collect[]:
        - filefd
        - filesystem
        - xfs

  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['tasks.cadvisor']
        type: 'A'
        port: 8080
```

In Prometheus, if I execute query - `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` it gives results like -

```
✔container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cpu="cpu15",id="/user.slice",instance="10.0.1.220:8080",job="cadvisor"}
✔container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cpu="cpu15",id="/user.slice",instance="10.0.1.219:8080",job="cadvisor"}
```

I can see `instance` having values `10.0.1.219:8080` and `10.0.1.220:8080` but these are not ip addresses of machines in swarm.

How can I differentiate which instance is for which machine? Is there something which I should configure?

Comment: Maybe you can check at the service discovery menu (/service-discovery) of your Prometheus instance if there is any type of "Discoverd labels" that has the info you want. If yes, than you can use [relabeling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) to put the values you want at the `instance` target label.

Comment: Under service discovery, I could see address same as instance - `__address__="10.0.1.219:8080"` hence unable to identify corresponding machine.